# Have to build signed APK twice, in order to avoid corrupt file?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Running `Eclipse Kepler`. My app has the following projects:

1. `FacebookSDK` (library)
2. `com.myapp.main` (library)
3. `com.myapp.main.free` (application)
4. `com.myapp.main.pro` (application)

Additional notes:

- All projects are dependent on the `Android Support Library v4`.
- Both apps are dependent on the two libraries.
- Proguard is disabled for all projects.
- Target is *android-19* for my projects, *android-8* for FacebookSDK.

When I want to release any of my two apps, I right-click on the application project and choose:

`Android Tools` -> `Export Signed Application Package...`

### The Problem

The APK installs correctly, but the app crashes immediately. Now, if I build the signed APK *one more time* using the `Export Application Package...` command, the app works perfectly. It's apparent that my project setup somehow fools the compiler to build a corrupt file. I have googled this. Nothing!

**What could be the cause of this weird behavior?**

It would be helpful to know the exact commands that are run when when this export wizard is run.

### UPDATE

When I activate ProGuard, I get some warnings that might indicate a problem:

```
 [proguard] Preparing output jar [C:\App\com.myapp.main.pro\bin\proguard\obfuscated.jar]
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [C:\App\com.myapp.main.pro\bin\proguard\original.jar]
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [C:\App\com.myapp.main\bin\classes.jar]
 [proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [C:\App\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1\facebook\bin\classes.jar]
 [proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [C:\App\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar]
 [proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
```

### UPDATE 2

I have googled this all day. The only relevant piece of information I can find is this:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27612

The `project.properties` file contains this line (note that removing this line does not solve the original problem):

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

The `proguard-project.txt` contains these additional paramaters:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** {
    *;
}
```

Comment: What does LogCat tell you when the app crashes after the first install?

Comment: Not sure, but I did get a weird exception log once. It crashed when indexing `SomeEnum.class.getEnumConstants()` even though the index was perfectly valid (`SomeEnum` has 6 values): `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5` It made no sense, so I assumed the APK was corrupt.

Comment: Is this code in a library or an application project?

Comment: 99% of the code is in the `com.myapp.main` library. The apps are just minor resource tweaks of that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is really simple. Remove the support library from the Facebook SDK and point it to the one in your application.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unable to test this as I ended up using Gradle in Android Studio. Have you verified your suggested solution?

Comment: Fair enough. Accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, I strongly recommend to clean and rebuild the project each time you want to build a signed APK. I also get weird exceptions from time to time if I forget to clean the project.

It's usually due to the autogenerated files (like R.java) not being updated correctly, but it can sometimes happen in library projects because the compiler precompiles (pre-dex) them. Here it probably used an outdated precompiled version of your library instead of the new one.

Not sure why that happens, though.

Comment: I have definitely seen this. Cleaning is crucial if I want to release both apps. What I don't understand is that I need to build twice when releasing *one* of the apps.

Comment: I noticed that the first time my app is built, it is 2 MB less than the second time. If I run this first build, it doesn't find my Application class.

Comment: @l33t Can you post your proguard configuration file?